# Drew Wilson AutoSuggest and Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, autosuggest

I am trying to get Ajax to work with [this plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin).

I have this code;

```
$.post("/Search/jQuery_GetSkillList", { q:""}, function (jSonData) {
  $("#AutoSuggest").autoSuggest(jSonData, { selectedItemProp: "name", selectedValuesProp: "value", searchObjProps: "name", startText: "Type skills here" });
});
```

which works fine but the potential items is in the 1,000's so I really need it to work as you type.

So I try this;

```
$("#AutoSuggest").autoSuggest("/Search/jQuery_GetSkillList", { selectedItemProp: "name", selectedValuesProp: "value", searchObjProps: "name", startText: "Type skills here" });
```

My controller, in both instances, is being called correctly and it returns the same data.

However, the second code snippet does not render the returned results whereas the first does.

Any ideas?

Comment: Drew Wilson? Is that an author's name or something?

Comment: yeah it is.  http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin.  have updated the question to include link

Comment: I know this is a very specific question but it's the only auto suggest plugin i can find that allows me to select more than one item.  much like the SO tag box.

Comment: Can you post the response json from `/Search/jQuery_GetSkillList`? Make sure it's the complete response object but with only a few items

Comment: it's a list of objects that have two properties.  [name] and [value].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that are interested I found the answer.

I included the un-packed version of the control and located a line that said `$.json` and made it `$.post` instead and now the control works very very well.

Thanks to those that spent time on this.

```
</griegs>
```

Comment: Hi.  I have the same problem, but I didn't found $.json, I found $.getJSON, and change that for $.post and $.get, but still not works, I have the 1.4v of autoSuggest. Any other idea?  grettings.

Comment: No sorry, you may want to post a new question to get the SO community onto it